# No output from cout when using SDL

Tags: c++, sdl

Sorry for my newbie-ness

Does anyone have problems getting std::cout to output when using SDL?

I can't seem to get anything shown in the output even when I comment away the SDL codes.

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <SDL.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv){
    //if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0){
    //  std::cout << "SDL_Init Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    //  return 1;
    //}
    //SDL_Quit();

    std::cout << "Testing" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Edited: The window was closed too fast to see anything, so I added SDL_Delay(2000); after my std::cout, and I saw my output :)

Comment: One thought might be that the window disappears too quick to see something.  Try putting sleep(5); after your cout statement.

Comment: Does to program return success or failure? And therefore, which of the cout statements is not showing?

Comment: SDL 1.2? The output is redirected to [files.](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/FAQ_Console)

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, I just added SDL_Delay(2000); and the message show, thank you :)

Comment: So how can I redirect the output from file to console again? Sorry, I'm new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting @Jonathan comment as the answer.

*One thought might be that the window disappears too quick to see something. Try putting sleep(5); after your cout statement*